# How do I find how far in the list a specific element of the list is? In other words, the location of a specific element in a list of results

Tags: python, list

I have a function that ends up putting the results on the list. I then use max(my_list) to give me the maximum of that list. It gives 12. But now I want to now how far into this list the maximum lies. So I can find the corresponding element of another list my_angles

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the built-in functions or numpy.

**Built-in functions**

```
my_list = [0, 5, 4, 9, -2, 6]
max_value = max(my_list)
idx = my_list.index(max_value)
print(max_value) # 9
print(idx) # 3
```

**Numpy**

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [0, 5, 4, 9, -2, 6]
idx = np.argmax(my_list)
max_value = my_list[idx]
print(max_value) # 9
print(idx) # 3
```